# iPhone - UIWebview - Changing the content dynamically

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I'm using a uiwebview in my application which shows some web pages from my server.
My web pages will have a tag

dynamic_string

In my application after getting web page from my server, i want to change the above mentioned tag with some dynamic text. (The dynamic text will be replaced with either with breaking news or cricket/football match score etc) I just want to replace the tag.

I'm using the following line of code to get the content of the webview.

```
NSMutableString* docText = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"]];
```

But after changing the content I'm not able to refresh he uiwebview.

Answer (score 0):

[webView loadRequest:]

call that method again

Comment: loadRequest looks for URL as paramter, but I've edited text. Even if I use loadHTML or loadData, t throws security exception. Did you try that?

Comment: Here is what I tried - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
  web = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)] ;
 [self.view addSubview:web];
 [web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.co.in"]]];
 [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(reloadWeb) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void)reloadWeb
{
 [web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.msn.com"]]];

}
Can you post the log of exception you are getting?

Comment: hmm... didn't tried to reload using HTML, if you can give me the two html texts, may be I can try it out at my end.